# I accidentally formatted my USB flash drive to "squashfs" and I need to be able to access it's files from a windows system

Tags: usb-drive, format-conversion, squashfs

Basically the title, I have no idea how it was formatted to squashfs, and when I run disks, the format button is greyed out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user68186 Yes, I can access and copy files to my Ubuntu system. But I'm trying to format it back to NTFS, but in disks, the format option is greyed out.

Comment: @user68186 I was able to unmount the drive, but even after I unmouted, the format option was still grey. Do you think it has to do with the fact the squashfs is read-only?

Comment: You could always try and re-format it from the terminal: `sudo lsblk -f` to find the name of the pen drive, `sudo fdisk /dev/sdx` (replace sdx with your device name), `p` will show you the partitions on the device, `d` will enable you to delete a partition (delete all partitions if that's what you want to do), `n` to add a new partition (select `p` for Primary, then accept defaults to use entire pen drive), then press `t` to set the partition type, enter `7` for exFAT/NTFS, and then `w` to write the changes to exit. Then from terminal: `sudo mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdx1` (replace sdx1 as needed).